# Subscripting a string literal

Tags: c++

Is subscripting an alphanumeric a common/valid technique? And what are the implicit conversions that take place ? [example](http://ideone.com/ROr8gH) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int k(2);
    cout << "Hello"[k] << endl;
    cout << (k-1)["Hello"] << endl;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "common" or "valid"? What would be wrong with this (apart from the fact that it's pointless since you could just do `cout << 'H'` as well?)

Comment: _'common/valid technique?'_ Valid maybe, common no!

Comment: @user3477950 Common : A common practice, oftenly seen in code. Valid : Safe, non error prone

Comment: I think it's reasonable to forget about the "common" part and concentrate on the "valid" question for now. If it's not valid, it sure isn't going to be common.

Comment: The one place this is common is in obfuscated code contests. It's rather pointless outside of that.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou You won't see often that one subscripts a string literal per se (just because), but you will definitely see functions subscripting other strings, which may or may not be literals. As to if it's safe: it's only as safe as any other thing involving pointer arithmetic. It's good as long as you use it correctly.

Comment: Perfectly valid. A string literal is just an array of (const) characters. The `2["Hello"]` form is very rare, and usually used with the intent to be obscure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is no greate sense to write

cout << "Hello"[0] << endl;

instead of simple

cout << 'H' << endl;

However sometimes there is something as

```
#define Hello "Hello"
```

in some (especially C) programs.

In this case there is some sense to write

cout << Hello[0] << endl;

However it would be much better to define

```
const char *Hello = "Hello";
```

or

```
const char Hello[] = "Hello";
```

There is no difference between

```
"Hello"[0]
```

and

```
0["Hello"]
```

because according to the C++ Standard

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

However the second record only confuses readers of the code.

As for the conversion then lvalue of string literal "Hello" that has type `const char[6]` is converted to type `const char *`. and then expression *((E1)+(E2)) is calculated using the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Per ISO 9899:201x: 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting: "**One** of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’." Emphasis mine.

Comment: I provided an example where the index is a variable. Sorry for altering the question, I only saw your answer afterwards. Ofcourse "Hello"[0] has no meaning.

Answer (score 8):

It's not particular common to index literal strings, but it has its uses, e.g.

```
auto hex_digit( int const value )
    -> char
{
    assert( 0 < value && value < 0x10 );
    return "0123456789ABCDEF"[value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly valid. Very little typecasting is involved.

Consider that the language element `"Hello"` actually means

```
  const char * anonymousVariable = "Hello";
```

Then `anonymousVariable[1]` yields a char with value `'e'`, and `anonymousVariable[1123]` yields something unpredictable.

Is it a good idea to write code this way?  It may or may not be, depending on the pattern you're trying to use.